# What is the best way to store data from Firebase to SQLite or offline in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my app when user is offline, I want data to store in local db and then sync data with firebase.

Comment: just turn on the persistent data in firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both FireStore and Realtime Database have offline persistence.

Firestore :

```
Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: true)
```

[image: answer]

In the case of Firebase Realtime database, you don't need anything specific to set-up. Offline connectivity is automatic. So, the following line does the trick :

```
databaseReference.child(dbKey).set(data);
```

Comment: Firestore.instance.enablePersistence(true).              i have try this but i dont get any collection method

Comment: Try and let me know if the following works : `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: true)`.

Comment: i got only 2 method then and when complete

Comment: its work but i have 2 collection 1st is user with user detail and 2nd is payment.    when user do payment  at that time i reduce(minus) money from user collection total balance filed.   but here in offline mode first transaction`s entry inserted after network coming but balance is not reduced.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as 'accepted' so that others can be befitted as well. In theory, the balance reduction issue should be mentioned as a separate question. However, here is one solution option popped-up in my mind. : Create a Firebase cloud function. Write balance reduction logic in there. The function will be triggered on the Firestore data insert/update/delete.

Comment: Writing a Firebase Cloud Function will help in two ways. In case, the user logs in on two devices (say mobile and desktop), your data won't be messed-up because of offline connectivity. The balance calculations will be always correct based on the incoming transactions.

Comment: okay i have posted new question of offline firebase data manage please suggest if you know.