# how to manage offline firebase database in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have manage offline firebase data using

```
 Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
```

i got this solution from [What is the best way to store data from Firebase to SQLite or offline in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315478/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-data-from-firebase-to-sqlite-or-offline-in-flutter)

but now its working fine but in firebase operation its not goes to next step.
my code is :

```
 showLoader();
   print("2222222222222222");

    DocumentReference ref = await _databaseReference
        .collection(FirebaseCollection.transcation)
        .add(param).catchError((onError){
          hideLoader();
          print("5555555  $onError");
    }).then((onValue){
      print("44444444444 $onValue");
    });

    print("33333333333");

    var token = '';
    var receiverId = '';
    .collection(FirebaseCollection.user)
      .document(userId)
      .get()
      .then((document) async {
    UserModel userModel = UserModel.fromsnapshot(document);
     print("data");
   }
```

here i have debug but print only 2222222222 nothing else.
i dont able to hide my loader or another task perform when my device is offline.

Comment: Add a try-catch block and please share the exception details, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use offline persistence in Firestore, don't use Transactions or `await` for response.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as i implemented bloc pattern, in constructor of repository, i did check connection status, and depending on that i go online/offline.

Rest of the code stays same, so i still use await and so.

```
bool online = ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance().currentStatus;
    if(online){
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOnline();
      _databasePropertiesReference.keepSynced(true);
    }else{
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOffline();
    }
```